# Is there a way to make multiple $push operations in a single pymongo update_one statement?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to simultaneously update two arrays in a single mongo doc (in a python shell). When I run the code below it seems to work fine until I see that only the second of the two arrays has been changed. I've tried using similar code where I have updated using $set and $push simultaneously and this seems to work fine but not using the $push operator twice in a single update_one statement.

```
>>> mongo = MongoClient()
>>> result = mongo.db.stuff.insert_one({'a':[], 'b':[]})
>>> result.inserted_id
ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd')
>>> mongo.db.stuff.update_one({'_id':ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd')}, {'$push': {'a':'1'}, '$push': {'b':'2'}})
<pymongo.results.UpdateResult object at 0x105aac460>
>>> mongo.db.stuff.find_one({'_id':ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd')})
{u'a': [], u'_id': ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd'), u'b': [u'2']}
```

Any ideas on what might be going on here and how to make it work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line

```
mongo.db.stuff.update_one({'_id':ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd')}, {'$push': {'a':'1'}, '$push': {'b':'2'}})
```

to

```
mongo.db.stuff.update_one({'_id':ObjectId('56694d602fdf6a293fef8ebd')}, {'$push': {'a':'1','b':'2'}})
```

Your code didn't work because it was not an actual json that you were passing. `{'$push': {'a':'1'}, '$push': {'b':'2'}}` will evaluate to `{'$push': {'b':'2'}}` since you cannot have two keys of same name in same level of json. This can be easily simulated in mongo console.

```
> var a = {'$push': {'a':'1'}, '$push': {'b':'2'}}
> a
{ "$push" : { "b" : "2" } }
```